How do I approach modeling a power bank
I'm a beginner in blender and I'm having a difficulty figuring out the correct method to model a power bank that appears to have different roundness in two parts.  I tried beveling the whole object together but it gave me equal roundness on the side and on top. I also tried using the weight property in the bevel modifier, specified the weights for the edges, got the the different bevels I wanted, but the vertices ended up overlapping and created problems with my mesh
Also, what should be order of modeling this object:

Basic shape and roundness
Screen and button
Subdivision and shade smooth
Boolean operations for port cuts

Any help would be much appreciated!




Hello and welcome. Could you show what you have so far? Please edit your post and include some screenshots of your progress and where exactly you are stuck.

Polygonal modeling is going to be destructive sooner or later (don't buy into hype if you see some add-on demos).
There is no one and only way to create a 3D model of something. You could use different modeling techniques for similar end results. Each have their own benefits and drawbacks, some are faster, some create artifacts sometimes and so on.
This is how I would go about it.
First evaluate the model and identify which operations you can use on certain areas. When you have figured out the most, start blocking the shape.
Make the larger shapes first, then make sure your proportions are ok.
Then do the large rounded bevels, if you didn't somehow loft the shape. There is no magic one button to "fix it for me".
Then cut the holes. Flat areas are usually easier to to tweak later, curved areas with a lot faces and verts obviously are harder to modify, usually it is best to redo such area if you need to do a change.
Between each step, try to check your models dimensions and if you are happy, continue.
Finally add the smaller bevels if required, as a final touch.
Keep intermediate models in some collection as backup or save incremental file versions, in case you mess up something and you need some less botched version of your model.
Using modifiers will eventually always create bad geometry in some models, so be prepared to manually fix vertex locations and create new faces, or cut more support edges if you are creating a subdivision model. Don't expect that you can simply create a model and then mark the edges for bevel and then slap a modifier or two on top of your model and call it a day, this usually only works for simpler models. Be prepared to use several hours if not days on your models depending on complexity (and how well you already know how to go about such shape), if you are only starting to model something. There are tons of tutorials available nowadays, unlike 20 years ago.
Edit - here is a quick example how I would create a relatively similar object, using above mentioned workflow. It is not very exact, and I didn't eyeball details that well, but maybe it helps.


Thank you so much. This is very helpful. My only obstacle now is figuring out how to get clean topology after I made the holes for the ports.
